# Image upload with angular and node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, express, mean-stack

I have had this problem for some time now and I cant find a fix anywhere. What I want to do is allow users to update their avatars on their profiles. However, when I try to pass the file to my node server the formData field is empty. I have tried multiple solutions given by others and none of them have worked.

Here is my profile html component:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" >
  <input type="file" id="selectFile" name="selectFile" [disabled]="uploading" formControlName="selectFile" (change)="uploadImage($event)" >
</form>
```

Here is my profile typescript component:

```
uploadImage(evt) {
    this.createAuthenticationHeaders();
    const files = evt.target.files;
    console.log('Uploading file...', files);

    if (files.length > 0) {
      let file;
      let formData = new FormData();
      for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
         file = files[i];
         formData.append('selectFile', file);
      }
      console.log(formData);


     this.uploadService.updateImage(formData.get('selectFile')).subscribe(res => res.json());
   }
}
```

Here is my upload service:

```
updateImage(formdata) {
    let url = this.baseUrl + '/authentication/profile/avatar/update';
    console.log(formdata);
    return this.http.post(url, formdata).catch(this.errorHandler);
}
```

Here is where that request should be handled:

```
router.post('/profile/avatar/update', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.params);
    User.findOne({ _id: req.decoded.userId }).select('username email').exec((err, user) => {
        if (err) {
            res.json({ success: false, message: err });
        } else {
            if (!user) {
                res.json({ success: false, message: 'Could not find user' });
            } else {
                if (fs.existsSync('C:/Users/Jake/Desktop/apis/client/src/assets/uploads/profiles/' + user.username + user.username + '/avatar.png')) {
                    res.json({ success: true, message: '../../assets/uploads/profiles/' + user.username + user.username + '/avatar.png' });
                } else {
                    res.json({ success: false, message: '../../assets/uploads/profiles/default/default.jpg' });
                }
            }
        }
    })
});
```

However the problem is occurring in the profile typescript component. Without using formData.get('selectFile'), the formData field is empty and I can't figure out why its not being filled.

Thank you in advance for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

Your frontend code looks good. You can use "express-fileupload" package and configure it in your express app

something like this

```
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');

app.use(fileUpload());
```

at route side

```
router.post('/profile/avatar/update', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.files); // this will contain your file.

});
```

Answer (score 0):

For nodejs you can use multer. Please see below as the basic example of usage. For more details you can check [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)

```
var express = require('express')
var multer  = require('multer')
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })

var app = express()

app.post('/profile', upload.single('avatar'), function (req, res, next) {

})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [express-fileupload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload) I used it in many projects, It is easier to implement and configure.